# Refreshing Windows Firewall ACLs without reboot

Tags: group-policy, windows-firewall

I am using GPOs to configure Windows Firewall ACLs.

As the title says: Is there a way to refresh modified ACLs without having to reboot each time? Running `gpupdate /target:computer` seems not to be enough... come on Microsoft seriously? What am I missing?

Comment: tried with gpupdate /force on the machine receiving the gpo?

Comment: Yes, tried that too, but no luck! Even restarting the Firewall Service _after_ the gpo refresh does not help.... naah

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but there is shockingly not an abundance of information regarding Windows FW rule management via GPO:

This has to do with group policy applied FW rules only updating the registry path at hklm\software\policies\microsoft\windowsfirewall\firewallrules.  For example, when you try to enumerate the FW rules throgh netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all, and compare the rule list to the GUI (wf.msc), the GUI will show the ones netsh sees plus those that have been added via GPO/the registry key above.

Based on my observation and testing the FW service (MPSSVC) only appears to read these keys on initialization.  Under normal user & group policy processing operations, this service cannot be stopped, which is why your updated FW GPO rules don't take effect until a reboot, while I am guessing that the registry keys are being added for you at the time of the gpupdate.

As an alternative, if you must push FW rules on the fly via GPO, I would think that it might be simpler to use a logon or startup script that uses new-netfirewallrule to add them directly to wherever Windows is hosting the netsh firewall rule store.